# How to remove a NaN column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file has 3 columns like:

```
1  2  3
2  4  6
3  6  9
```

I want to arrange it like:

```
wave  shape  freq
  1     2      3
  2     4      6
  3     6      9
```

I used the following script:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


import_file = glob.glob('data.txt')
for files in import_file:
     intial_data = pd.read_csv(files, header=None, delimiter="\t").values
     table = pd.DataFrame(intial_data, columns = ['wave' , 'shape', 'freq')
      print(table)
```

It gave me this

Error: Shape of passed values is (4, 150), indices imply (3, 150)

I replaced the line which arranges and describe the table by adding another column indicator X

```
table = pd.DataFrame (intial_data, columns = ['wave' , 'shape', 'freq','x'])
```

Thin it's working good and gave me this result

```
       wave     shape    freq     x
 0    1.0000   2.0000   3.0000   NaN
 1    2.0000   4.0000   6.0000   NaN
 2    3.0000   6.0000   9.0000   NaN
```

I can't understand what us NaN column and I need to remove it from my work

Please, any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.dropna(1,'all')
```

Output:

```
   wave  shape  freq
0   1.0    2.0   3.0
1   2.0    4.0   6.0
2   3.0    6.0   9.0
```

Or alternatively you can just read the first 3 columns from your file with `usecols` parameter of `pd.read_csv`. With the following code you get your `table` variable straight without reading `intial_data` first:

```
table = pd.read_csv(files,
                    header=None,
                    delimiter="\t",
                    usecols=range(3),
                    names=['wave', 'shape', 'freq'])
```

Comment: So the user should write `3` hardcoded in the code? What if you don't know the number of columns beforehand?

Comment: That would be a different problem. Your code would also not work if nan column is found between 2 non-nan columns (which is also a different problem). Drop would work in all these cases

Comment: Also OP is setting column names to be ['wave' , 'shape', 'freq'], so I suppose we know how many columns we have, otherwise this would not be possible

Comment: @perl Well, your first argument didn't convince me, because having `NaN`s in the middle could be alright (they'd likely be wanted). But your last comment is fair ;}

Comment: @RafaelC: so if `nan` in the middle is wanted, then we have to use `sep='\t'` and not `delim_whitespace=True` or `sep='\s+'`, right? For example, if I have a line "1\t2\t\t3\t", with `sep='\t'` it becomes [1,2,np.nan,3,np.nan], but with `delim_whitespace=True` or `sep='\s+'` we get [1,2,3]

Comment: Ops, true ;} so my could *would* work also with NaNs in between ! The thing is: if they are in the middle and are wanted, then they'd likely be saved as "NaN" and not as a blank space

Answer (score 2):

Do not take the suggestions of dropping the `NaN`s. That would be a solution to an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) rather than a solution to the *cause*.

Use instead

```
intial_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

or

```
intial_data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
```

The reason why you get this error is because your `data.txt` file has an extra tab in the end. `pandas` interprets that as an extra column of `NaN`s.

So, even though you *see*

```
1  2  3
2  4  6
3  6  9
```

what you most likely have is

```
1\t2\t3\t
2\t4\t6\t
3\t6\t9\t
```

The last `\t` adds the extra column.

Comment: @etshoo so `open(data.txt).read()` and investigate what is the true separator ;)

Comment: @RafaelCe the separator is \t

Comment: @etshoo mind posting exactly why `open(data.txt).read()` outputs? (of course, just the few first lines)

Comment: 298.08  1.8292  1.8236  
299.52  1.8362  1.8306  
300.97  1.8434  1.8378  
302.44  1.8507  1.8452  
303.92  1.8581  1.8527

Comment: @etshoo not the values, but the actual string (where we can see the `\n` and `\t` characters)